# How to use JSPM overrides in SystemJS config file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, systemjs, jspm

My JSPM version: `0.17.0-beta.5`.
My project is using ES6 style `import` statement using TypeScript.

### So...

I installed `angular-ui-router` like so:

`jspm install angular-ui-router`

This saves the following lines to my `package.json`:

```
"jspm" {
  "overrides": {
    "github:angular-ui/ui-router@0.2.17": {
        "directories": {
          "lib": "release"
        },
        "format": "cjs",
        "main": "angular-ui-router",
        "registry": "jspm",
        "dependencies": {
          "angular": "^1.3.2"
        },
        "meta": {
          "angular-ui-router.js": {
            "deps": [
              "angular"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      // ... other stuff
```

Great! So it says the file that should be loaded is located in the **release** folder.

But in my browser, I load my `jspm.conf.js` file, which says:

```
SystemJS.config({
  "packages": {
    "github:angular-ui/ui-router@0.2.17": {
      "map": {
        "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.9"
      }
    },
  }

  // ... little further

  "map": {
    "angular-ui-router": "github:angular-ui/ui-router@0.2.17"
  }
```

So there is no notion there that `SystemJS` should look in the **release** folder as I mentioned above. Therefor, I can't import like

`import 'angular-ui-router'`

but only like

`import angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router`

How do I use the overrides from `package.json` in my SystemJS config file `jspm.config.js` which is loaded in the browser?

Comment: Have you been able to solve it?

Comment: updating JSPM should fix this. Currently using 0.17.0-beta.32.